# What is the Time Complexity of mutable.HashSet.keys

Tags: scala, data-structures, hashmap, time-complexity

Suppose i'm implement the following class:

```
class Foo{
  val set = new mutable.HashSet[Int, Int]()

  def add(key: Int, value: Int) = {
    // do-stuff
    set.put(key, value)
  }

  def iterate() = {
    //iterate through all keys
  }
}
```

My question is regarding an efficient implementation of `iterate`
I could simply use `set.keys` and iterate through the `Iterable[Int]`, but will `keys` return in constant time, or does it construct an `Itearble` in linear time?

I know that i will receive all the keys one-by-one. Would implementing a `mutable.HashSet` just to store all the keys as they come in be overkill?
Something like

```
class Foo{
  val set = new mutable.HashSet[Int, Int]()
  val keys = new mutable.HashSet[Int]()

  def add(key: Int, value: Int) = {
    // do-stuff
    set.put(key, value)
    keys += key

  }

  def iterate() = {
    //iterate through all keys
    keys.foreach(f=>{

    })
  }
}
```

Is their a more efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: `keys` returns in constant time, iterating them is order **N** as with any iteration over any collection.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Could you please provide the source of your claim.

Comment: Well, first you probably mean `HasMap` instead of `HashSet`. Then, if take a look to the [source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.2/src/library/scala/collection/Map.scala#L177) you will see that it actually just creates a dummy object that keeps a reference over the original map, so getting each key is just iterating over each element of the map and sicarding the value. So, creating the keys iterable is **O(1)**.